# Running a Python script for k seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a Python script that reads the serial monitor in order to get sensor readings from an Arduino. I've been trying to solve the following problem: I want my script to run exactly for one minute in order to get the data and process it offline. For instance, if I execute the following script, it should be running for a minute and then stop. I have tried using the time module or the sleep function but my script keeps getting data and does not stop. I'm not sure how to break the while loop. Until now I managed to stop the execution by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but it's necessary for the script to stop on its own. Here's my code(I'm also posting the get_readings function):

python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import chair_functions as cf
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_extension = '.txt'
    rec_file = 'chair_'+cf.get_date()+file_extension    
    raw_data = cf.create_directories()
    rec_file = os.path.join(raw_data,rec_file)
    cf.get_readings(rec_file)


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from serial import Serial
import pandas as pd
import collections
import logging
import serial
import time
import sys
import csv 
import os 

def get_readings(output_file):
    """Read the data stream coming from the serial monitor 
       in order to get the sensor readings
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    output_file : str
        The file name, where the data stream will be stored
    """
    serial_port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
    baud_rate = 9600
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port,baud_rate)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=output_file,level=logging.DEBUG,format="%(asctime)s    %(message)s")
    flag = False
    while True:
        try:
            serial_data = str(ser.readline().decode().strip('\r\n')) 
            time.sleep(0.2)
            tmp = serial_data.split('  ')[0] #Getting Sensor Id
            if(tmp == 'A0'):
                flag = True
            if (flag and tmp != 'A4'):
                #print(serial_data) 
                logging.info(serial_data)
            if(flag and tmp == 'A4'):
                flag = False
                #print(serial_data)         
                logging.info(serial_data)   
        except (UnicodeDecodeError, KeyboardInterrupt) as err:
            print(err)
            print(err.args)
            sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Start a timer at begin and check its values regularly. Stop when it is more than 60 seconds.

Comment: I tried it, too. Unfortunately, it doesn't work properly. If I remove the while loop it executes successfuly

Comment: Instead of `True`, set `start = timer.time()`, then `while time.time() - s < 60:`.

Comment: No, as I said the time module doesn't work

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that. I know it is not a solution, but since the other part of the while are not that much time consuming maybe you can use a `for _ in range(300)` (because of the 0.2 seconds sleep).

Comment: The 0.2 sec sleep is used for another reason(I actually collect sensor readings as tuples of 5 so in order to get the data in this format I needed to slow the stream a bit). I have also two more modalities(keyboard and mouse), so if I solve the while loop stopping problem I will also solve the same problem for the twoo more modalityes

Comment: @am.rez Dude you just saved my ass in my thesis! This: Instead of True, set start = timer.time(), then while time.time() - s < 60 is a brilliant idea and it worked! Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `time` module itself that does not work. Therefore, instead of using `True` for the while condition, set `start = timer.time()`, then `while time.time() - start < 60`: as below:

```
start = time.time()
while time.time() - start < 60:
    ...
```